# Creating an extended partition

Tags: partition, hard-disk

I'm trying to create an extended partition. In GParted, I shrunk the size of the existing partition and now want to create a new EXTENDED partition in the free, unallocated space. GParted only lets me create a PRIMARY partition. What am I doing wrong here?

You can actually ignore the flag for the swap as "boot." That was me just messing around trying to get it to work. I've removed that flag. Not sure how the question of boot affects all of this...maybe it factors in somehow.

Answer (score 2):

You already have an extended partition. Unless you go through hoops, you can only have a single extended partition, but it can contain as many logical partitions as you want. Filesystems live on primary partitions (of which you can have at most 3, or 4 if you don't have an extended partittion) or logical partitions. The extended partition is only a container for logical partitions.

Resize the extended partition `sdc2` to occupy more space, and create a new logical partition `sdc6` (and more if desired) inside the extended partition.

Comment: Gilles, oh wow and it was staring me in the face the whole time. Thanks so much!!! wait, uh oh. GParted won't let me do anything with sdc2. No option to resize...

Comment: Filesystems have nothing to do with partitioning. You can have a filesystem on any partition whether it's a primary or a extended partition.

Comment: @LuxuryMode: I thought you could resize an extended partition with GParted. Try creating a logical partion, maybe. If all else fails, at this point, you can just delete the swap partition and start again.

Comment: @Deleted: Yes, technically you can put a filesystem on an extended partition, but it'll be very confusing.

Comment: @Gilles: How? Extended partitions just show up an any other partition. There's no difference running mkfs on /dev/sda1 as /dev/sda7, if it's a valid partition than you can create a file system on it. It the same on Windows, Disk Administrator can create FAT32 or NTFS filesystems on extended partitions. I don't know why you would find it confusing.

Comment: @Deleted: Oh, I see. You're mixing up logical partitions with extended partitions. Read my answer.

Comment: @Giles: Um, no offense but "logical" partitions are the partitions created from "extended" partitions. An extended partition uses the space from a primary partition to create the partition map for "logical" partitions. An extended partition isn't a real partition, it just hold the partition maps for the logical partitions. Any modern OS sees logical partitions just like primary partitions. I have 4 OS's on my laptop and 6 partitions with the 3 Linux distro's sharing a swap partition. I had no problem creating filesystems or installing OS's on my "logical" partitions.

Comment: @LuxuryMode you have to unmount sdc5 (it's being used for swap) and then sdc2 first before you can do anything to sdc2.